# Ugly overflows when editing a deleted answer inline

Tags: bug, design, deleted-answers

Go to a site where you have inline post editing privileges. Make an answer, then delete it. Edit the deleted answer. You'll get something that looks like this:

[image: eek]

As you can see, the editor and the preview box are overflowing the right edge of the purplish deleted-post background. I assume this is not a desired behavior.

(Behavior observed on meta.Anime.SE in Chrome 32.0.1700.76 on Windows 7, with no userscripts active.)

Comment: Only few pixels but yeah, agree it should not overflow, especially not on Stack Overflow. ;)

Comment: Ugly Overflows?? This seems like a real roundabout way to complain about the design of the sites! ;-)

Comment: This seems to have been fixed as a side effect of the recent general redesign.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that the borders and margins for the inline editor take up a few pixels more horizontal space than is normally available within the post area, causing them to overflow off the right edge.  Normally this isn't really noticeable, since there's no visible boundary at the edges of the post area, but the pink background on deleted posts makes it very obvious.

Making the editor narrower isn't very practical, especially not for the preview area, which should simultaneously have the same inner width as the normal post area (to keep things like text wrapping consistent) *and* have a visible border on each side.

However, conveniently, there's plenty of space on the *left* side of the post area for the editor to expand into, if we just allow it to.  The easiest way to do this is to give the editor `<div>` a small negative left margin, like this:

```
.inline-editor { margin-left: -4px }
```

While waiting for the SE devs to fix this, I have added the CSS rule above to the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), a collection of client-side CSS and JavaScript fixes packaged as a GreaseMonkey-style user script.  If you're using a compatible browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, possibly Safari and others, but unfortunately not IE or most mobile browsers), please give it a try!